# problem with ros fuerte install on opensuse 11.2

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The ros opensuse install page has just been updated recently and I was trying out the installation on old opensuse. I'd like to update the ros wiki regarding installing ros on opensuse with my findings.

I am facing an issue that when I run
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
I get the following error

```
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:13 (message):
   Error executing process with arguments COMMAND
   /home/mandeep/ros-underlay/build/env.sh /usr/bin/python
   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/empy-3.1-py2.7.egg/em.pyc --raw-errors -F
   /home/mandeep/ros-underlay/catkin/cmake/empy_util.py -F
   /home/mandeep/ros-underlay/build/catkin/pkg-config.pc.context.py -F
   /home/mandeep/ros-underlay/build/catkin/catkin-context.py -o
   /home/mandeep/ros-underlay/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/catkin.pc
   /home/mandeep/ros-underlay/catkin/cmake/em/pkg-config.pc.em
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:14 (safe_execute_process)
   catkin/cmake/catkin_project.cmake:115 (em_expand)
   catkin/CMakeLists.txt:24 (catkin_project)
```

Regards,
Mandeep

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32446/problem-with-ros-fuerte-install-on-opensuse-11.2/) by [Mandeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2236/mandeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running ccmake in the build directory, go over the available options and check if all path settings are OK. Maybe e.g. the python path on opensuse differs from ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Thanks Steven,
I found that cmake /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/empy-3.1-py2.7.egg/em.pyc was wrongly generated as my python module install(empy) had problem. I uninstalled empy using pip and then re-installed it from source instead of using easy_install.
Now the issue is fixed.
Regards,
Mandeep

---

Originally posted by [Mandeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2236/mandeep/) with karma: 11 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1